# How to enable ACH payment option Stripe

Tags: stripe

I am using CiviCRM 4.6 with Stripe extension 4.7.3. I am able to do payment by Credit Card, but unable to find option to enable ACH payment.

Has anyone know how to enable ACH payment option in CiviCRM Stripe.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if CiviCRM Stripe pp extension supports ACH(https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/issues/124). They might have beta version which is not released yet.

Comment: cheers mate :) (y)